# Complete function spaces and inner products

Tags: functional-analysis, statistics, inner-products, complete-spaces

I am reading the technical report by Leo Breimann entitled "Some Infinity Theory for Predictor Ensembles".

On page 4 he has the following:

> **Definition 1** Let $L_2(P)$ be the space of functions on $\mathbb{R}^D$ that are square - integrable wrt $P(dx)$. A set of functions $F$ in $L_2(P)$ will be called complete if the $L_2$-closure of all finite linear combinations of functions in $F$ by $L_2(F)$, equals $L_2(P)$.

And then the following property:

> **Property 1** A set of functions, $F$, is complete iff there is no non-zero fucntion $g$ in $L_2(P)$ s.t. $\langle g,f \rangle = 0 \forall f\in F$, where $\langle g,f \rangle = \int f(x)g(x)P(dx).$

I do not understand how Property 1 works. As far as my intuition goes, a zero inner product implies orthogonality. But any vector/function space should be able to be decomposed into an orthogonal set of basis vectors.

Thus property 1 as I understand seems to suggest that there cannot exist a function $g$ which makes the inner product 0,and so by implication there cannot exist an orthogonal set of basis vectors on a complete function space?

So property 1 seems to link completeness and orthogonality in a way which I can't fully grasp. I was hoping someone here could help clarify this understanding for me.

Link to paper:
https://statistics.berkeley.edu/tech-reports/579

Comment: You are missing the "for all $f$" part of the property. It can exist functions orthogonal to $g$, but not all.

Comment: I see thanks! Now it clicked. :)

Answer (score 1):

As the comment has pointed out

> You are missing the "for all f" part of the property. It can exist functions orthogonal to g, but not all

Thus there is allowed to exist a "zeroing" function for some $f$ but it cannot be true "for all" $f$, otherwise there will be "holes" in the space naturally.